# MySQL CONCAT() condition NETBEANS error

Tags: mysql, netbeans, concatenation

So im trying to make a search function for my application
and i have this line of code where in im having a problem with:

```
String searchQuery = "SELECT id,**CONCAT(first,' ',last)**
FROM `person` 
WHERE CONCAT(`id`,`first`,`last`) LIKE '%"+ValToSearch+"%'";
```

when i run my program and test the function the console returns this error
Column 'first' not found(Line 1).
if i remove the concat function and just use 'first' it does work. However i want it so that it shows both first and last name of the person

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I ask why you aren't using prepared statements?

Comment: Do you have a column named FIRST?

Comment: @juergend yes i do have a column named first

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i've tried using PS and it gives the same error.

Comment: And if you do `select first from person` it works?

Comment: but when i dont use concat on line 1 it does work.

Comment: @juergend yes sir

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my own problem.
Seems like the 2nd concat at the where statement uses the alias for the 1st concat.